# Sort core data nsarray numeric

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsarray

I've a problem sorting an nsarray.
The nsarray is filled with core data:

```
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"ReactionInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
self.scoreInfos_arr = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


for (ReactionInfo *info in self.scoreInfos_arr) {
    debug(@"%@ - %f",info.player,info.score);             
}
```

U see that I get the player name and the score.
My target is, to show the scores in a table view, but of course they should be sort numeric.

I didn't find a solution on how to sort this NSArray (self.scoreInfos_arr is it)

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a NSSortDescriptor

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                       [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"score"
                                                                    ascending:YES] autorelease]]];
```

Comment: thanks, thats an easy way to do it - thank you really much :-)